# Mail is marked as spam by gmail - no idea, why

Tags: email, spam, mac, gmail

I'm using my DSL-Business-connection for a small office.
I just installed a Mac Mini Server with mail-support and try to send an email to googlemmil, but this mail is getting marked as spam.
This is the header of my mail.

The IP is static and I set up the PTR and SPF.

What else can I do?

```
Delivered-To: testmailadresse12345-456789-1012345@gmail.com
Received: by 10.202.7.193 with SMTP id 184csp174199oih;
        Fri, 31 Oct 2014 03:42:56 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.112.97.135 with SMTP id ea7mr25452495lbb.46.1414752175877;
        Fri, 31 Oct 2014 03:42:55 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <ich@meinedomain.de>
Received: from buero.meinedomain.de (buero.meinedomain.de. [80.147.xx.xxx])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id ri5si15978175lbb.115.2014.10.31.03.42.55
        for <testmailadresse12345-456789-10@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Fri, 31 Oct 2014 03:42:55 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of ich@meinedomain.de designates 80.147.xx.xxx as permitted sender) client-ip=80.147.xx.xxx;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of ich@meinedomain.de designates 80.147.xx.xxx as permitted sender) smtp.mail=ich@meinedomain.de
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by buero.meinedomain.de (Postfix) with ESMTP id C17275486E9
    for <testmailadresse12345-456789-10@googlemail.com>; Fri, 31 Oct 2014 11:42:53 +0100 (CET)
X-Virus-Scanned: amavisd-new at meinedomain.de
Received: from buero.meinedomain.de ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (buero.meinedomain.de [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id GUEFHVd811Ma for <testmailadresse12345-456789-10@googlemail.com>;
    Fri, 31 Oct 2014 11:42:53 +0100 (CET)
Received: from [192.168.2.30] (unknown [192.168.2.30])
    by buero.meinedomain.de (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 9DAF75486DB
    for <testmailadresse12345-456789-10@googlemail.com>; Fri, 31 Oct 2014 11:42:53 +0100 (CET)
From: =?utf-8?Q?Mein_Name9Fler?= <ich@meinedomain.de>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Eine Testemail
Message-Id: <F7485894-1928-4091-B857-1E554F4F1FFF@meinedomain.de>
Date: Fri, 31 Oct 2014 11:42:52 +0100
To: testmailadresse12345-456789-10@googlemail.com
Mime-Version: 1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 8.0 \(1990.1\))
X-Mailer: Apple Mail (2.1990.1)

Hallo,

dies ist eine Testemail. Bitte vergesse den Termin am Sonntag nicht.

Danke Dir!`
```

Comment: Gmail _tells you_ why they marked it as spam.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup spf in you domain also setup dkim

I think [google help pages](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9008?hl=en) can help you in this questions